# Spring @DataNeo4jTest with Procedure Support

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-test, neo4j-apoc

I'm writing Spring Data Neo4J repository tests with `@DataNeo4jTest` and all is well until I write a test against a custom query that uses a procedure, for example `apoc.coll.intersection`. The error declares procedure `apoc.coll.intersection` is unknown. I have the APOC JAR on the classpath so am guessing I need to find a way to register the procedure with the embedded datasource/driver that `@DataNeo4jTest` uses.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with this for quite some time, trying different dependency versions and also playing with configuration code as suggested by @meistermeier I found a solution, which was to simply use the correct version of the 2 Neo4J test JARs I was referencing. This is a Spring Boot project so here are all the Neo4J dependencies in my Maven POM that solve the issue:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
  <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I set `neo4j.ogm.version` to match the version specified in the `spring-data-neo4j-parent` POM (which is brought in transitively).

Answer (score 1):

Some background to understand the situation: The `@DataNeo4jTest` annotation provides you the Spring Boot based auto configuration. It will pick up your Neo4j connection configuration in your `application.properties` (either test or production if no test properties are defined) and create Neo4j-OGM's `SessionFactory` with the matching configuration for you.

There are two ways to solve you problem:

Define the `SessionFactory` bean by yourself with embedded instance setup and configuration:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
  GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(Paths.get("pathToDb").toFile()).newGraphDatabase();

  registerProcedure(graphDatabaseService, MyProcedure.class);

  EmbeddedDriver driver = new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService);
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(driver, "package");
}
```

Or during "runtime" with the already existing `SessionFactory` bean e.g. in your test setup (make sure to do this just once)

```
EmbeddedDriver loadedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) sessionFactory.getDriver();
registerProcedure(loadedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService(), MyProcedure.class);
```

both will call a method like this

```
public static void registerProcedure(GraphDatabaseService db, Class<?>...procedures) throws KernelException {
    Procedures proceduresService = ((GraphDatabaseAPI) db).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(Procedures.class);
    for (Class<?> procedure : procedures) {
        proceduresService.registerProcedure(procedure,true);
        proceduresService.registerFunction(procedure, true);
        proceduresService.registerAggregationFunction(procedure, true);
    }
}
```

Update: Added example and version definitions.

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
    .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(Paths.get("path/to/db").toFile()).newGraphDatabase();

// Option I
registerProcedure(graphDatabaseService, MyProcedure.class);

EmbeddedDriver driver = new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(driver, "org.neo4j.ogmindex.domain");

// Option II if embedded driver is not directly accessible anymore
EmbeddedDriver loadedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) sessionFactory.getDriver();
// register the apoc version function
registerProcedure(loadedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService(), Version.class);

// Test call to apoc.version
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.query("RETURN apoc.version()", emptyMap())
    .forEach(System.out::println); // outputs {apoc.version()=3.4.0.2}
```

`pom.xml` definition for the example above:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-harness-enterprise</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.procedure</groupId>
    <artifactId>apoc</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've seen a few answer like this. Unfortunately the register methods on the `Procedures` interface do not exist. I've looked around for similar ones and cannot find any. My APOC JAR version is `3.4.0.2`.

Comment: Would you mind sharing relevant portions of a Maven POM or similar so I can try to mimic the versions? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I played around with it and still could not get the tests to run. After digging through Maven dependencies and some trial and error, I solved it with some dependency tweaks. I'll post my solution. Thanks for your help! I suspect it will still be helpful to others.